# Passing value of a java method to a javascript variable using Struts 2 tag

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, jstl

I have a JSP file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<% response.setContentType("application/javascript"); %>

var collegename = '<s:text name="student.collegename"/>';
```

student.collegename defined in messages.properties file.
now i can use collegename variable in java script file.

Is there any tag in Struts2 by using those i can pass the java value to a  java script variable ?

for example:

```
var jsvariable = 'string value of a java method';
```

I have used this but its not worked:
  Servlet code:  `HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

request.setAttribute("collegename", collegename);`

  JSP code:`var collegename= '<%=request.getAttribute("collegename")%>';`

Java Script code:`alert("collegename"+collegename)`
it show on IE:`'collegename' is undefined`

please suggest

i have also try this:
Action class:  `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
HttpServletRequest request;
            HttpServletRequest request =    ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        request.setAttribute("collegename", collegename);
             System.out.println("now getting attribute-----");
             String attr=(String) request.getAttribute("cname");
             System.out.println("attr is:::"+attr);`

getter/setter for collegename property.

JSP code:`<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<% response.setContentType("application/javascript"); %>
 var collegename= '<%=request.getAttribute("collegename")%>';`

Java Script code:`alert("collegename"+collegename)`

  it show on IE: 'collegename' is undefined

although it show getting attribute (college name) on console but it is not show on java script alert.
it show on IE: 'collegename' is undefined

please review.

Comment: what's the use of these files:
org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.prefs
org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs

Answer (score 4):

You can use some like code.

```
var jsvariable = '<%=request.getAttribute("testattribute")%>';
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Its not worked:  Servlet code:
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
request.setAttribute("collegename", collegename);

JSP code:
var collegename= '<%=request.getAttribute("collegename")%>';

Java Script code:
alert("collegename"+collegename)

it show on IE: 'collegename' is undefined

Comment: Is javascript returned from the server is right? Or var colleguename has empty value. So if alert(collegename) is undefined then your javascript was not invoked and var colleguename is not setted. If it was invoked and passing attribute wasn`t, then alert(colleguename)will return "". Can you show me your javascript code?

Comment: It looks like your javascript with colleguename variable is not executed.

Comment: So first you can try to output your request attribute on simple jsp page, then add it to script tag, then check if you include your script file right

Comment: when i print the attribute inside of java script function in a JSP, like this:script type="text/javascript">function eCollege(collegeID) {
var msg="<%=request.getAttribute("collegename")%>";  please suggest
alert(msg);
</script>

it show attribue value in alert box..which is fine.

but when i print the attribue value in JSP like:
<s:property value="<%=request.getAttribute("collegename")%>"/>

it show execption on console:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Comment: May be it`s late already but anyway. you could try to use <s:property value="#request.collegename"/>

Comment: Sorry for not responding for so long:)

Answer (score 4):

This will call the `getSomeValue()` method on your action class.

```
var collegename = '<s:property value="someValue" escapeJavaScript="true"/>';
```

Comment: sir, i have used your suggestion but it show on internet explorer: 'collegename' is undefined.
i have made property value regarding getter/setter in action class.
please review.

Comment: When you view source for the page, what is the resulting output for the line where collegename is defined? Is someValue being set in your action class?

Answer (score -1):

How about using EL like ${userName} or OGNL %{userName}...